# How can I map a function to a list and stop when a condition is fulfilled and tell me if it stopped or reached the end?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to apply a function over a list, but if, at any moment, a result returned by the function is of a certain kind, then I don't want to continue to iterate over the rest of the elements.

I know I could achieve this with this function:

```
example p f ls = takeWhile p $ map f ls
```

The thing is that I would like to know if it reached the end of the list, or if it failed to do so.

I thought of this function, but it seems a bit cumbersome:

```
haltmap :: Eq a => (a -> Bool) -> (b -> a) -> [a] ->  [b] -> Either [a] [a]
haltmap _ _ acc [] = Right acc
haltmap p f acc (h:t)
  | p output = Left acc
  | otherwise = haltmap p f (acc ++ [output]) t
  where output = f h
```

I use Left and Right to know if it went through the entire list or not.

I'm sure there's a better way to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use [span](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:span) for this.  It's like takeWhile but it gives you a pair with the remainder of the list as well as the matching part, like this:

```
> span (<3) [1,2,3,2,1]
([1,2],[3,2,1])
```

Then you can check if the remainder is empty:

```
haltmap :: (a -> Bool) -> (b -> a) -> [b] -> Either [a] [a]
haltmap p f xs = (if null rest then Right else Left) ys
  where
    (ys, rest) = span p (map f xs)
```

Comment: The problem is that the list is very long, and if i want to save on time complexity, then I need a function that does not traverse the entire list (which span does, unless under lazy evaluation, if I check if the remainder is empty, it only fetched the first element of the second part of the tuple to get the answer?).

Comment: It does indeed only check if there is a first element in the second list.  Try for example `haltmap (<5) (+1) [1..]`, it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foldr` for this. Because `go` does not evaluate the second argument unless needed, this will also work for infinite lists.  (Will Ness also had an answer that also used `foldr`, but it seems they've deleted it).

```hs
import Data.Bifunctor (bimap)

haltmap :: Eq a => (b -> Bool) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> Either [b] [b]
haltmap p f xs = foldr go (Right []) xs
  where
    go x a
      | p output = let o = (output:) in bimap o o a
      | otherwise = Left []
      where output = f x

main = do
  print $ haltmap (<5) (+1) [1..]
  print $ haltmap (<12) (+1) [1..10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU49T8MwEN39K97AYAsRNUgsEelQ0a0Ta@TBoU5j1ckZx1E78N/DOXx1YLDv6d7Hvd5MZ@v9srghUEx4MckUO9fN41uiCNm6wQQlRG98YoSqwv4dBvWWOTxssSPyKgNp8t@uuDE6j71LvY1oWp3fb0ZAh@uEGh35Y8SJIF/dqU9otGJCABe2WZ7I5BVmhcAHW2lOYU5s9jaBeMqvTaXgRqx1eU03HsolLm6yLD7YLp/55tYzf4ncSojBcEyNI7EmRDcm3OGnuHx@UpD3pUJTFoX@V1E@3kjKjV6WTw)

Using a tuple with a `Bool` may be easier, though.

```hs
import Data.Bifunctor (second)

haltmap :: Eq a => (b -> Bool) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> (Bool, [b])
haltmap p f xs = foldr go (True, []) xs
  where
    go x a
      | p output = second (output:) a
      | otherwise = (False, [])
      where output = f x

haltmap (<5) (+1) [1..]    //(False,[2,3,4])
haltmap (<12) (+1) [1..10] //(True,[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY69TsQwEIR7P8UUFLaAiCDRRNwVJ@AJ6CIXm4tDLJyssR3dFbx7cBJ@rqCxRzvfjKan@G6cm2c7eA4JT5SoONhuGo@JA2Q0Rx5bJURPLg3kUVV4/gBht4dscLvHgdmpRUha3mbVNen1tJg3qButfgs8OpwjdujYtQFvDPkaJpMprbIhgFNvgsk/FvMMWiXwmaM8JT@lHN52QW6HSl1QnHL@ZKPJmHwhF7fub38t/@vJW4QYyI5Zt5wZH@yYcIWfufLxQUFelwp1WRT6X6K8v0DKOz3PXw)

Comment: using a tuple seems much better to me. having the resulting list behind either Left or Right forces whole list to be created before returning it wrapped. with the tuple, a caller might access the list first, and only later check which case it was that it terminated on (if at all). so it is about being as lazy as possible. the reason I deleted was that my function also had to create the list in full, whereas your version indeed doesn't. the use case is calling e.g. `take 1 . snd` ...

Comment: ... `take 1 . snd`, and you can't do _that_ on an `Either` value. ---- the `span`-based version can easily be augmented to return the tuple, too, but `span` has its own problems -- it can create space leak, whereas the foldr version shouldn't. ( that's why I wanted to write the foldr-based code in the first place, but got sidetracked. for reference, it was `example p f ls = foldr g z ls h
  where {
  z h = Right (h []) ;
  h = id ;
  g x r h | not (p x) = Left (h []) | otherwise = r (h . (f x :)) }`. )

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with foldr, which is the following:

```
haltMap :: (a -> Bool) -> (b -> a) -> [b] -> Either [a] [a]
haltMap p f = foldr (\x acc -> if p x then Left []
                               else (either (\a -> Left (x:a)) (\b -> Right (x:b)) acc))
                    (Right []) . map f
```

Also, to return, instead of the partial list, the element which failed, all is needed it to change `Left []` to `Left x` in the `if` clause, and change the `(\a -> Left (x:a))` to `Left` in the `else` clause.

Comment: This is rather similar to my answer. You can use `bimap` instead of `either` to avoid writing `Left` and `Right` yourself.